# ROracle install

Tags: windows, roracle

I am having trouble getting the ROracle package to run on my computer.  I have windows 10 and R 3.5.1 (it worked on windows 7).
First Attempt:

```
install.packages("ROracle")
Installing package into 
‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of 
C/C++/Fortran: ‘ROracle’
These will not be installed
```

I followed the instructions here and downloaded it from Oracle directly
[How to install ROracle package on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046324/how-to-install-roracle-package-on-windows-7)

I also looked at these sites, but the suggestions don’t work their either.
[How to install ROracle package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232917/how-to-install-roracle-package)

[ROracle installation :: Unable to load shared object error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802847/roracle-installation-unable-to-load-shared-object-error)

[how to install r package for oracle on windows 10 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664588/how-to-install-r-package-for-oracle-on-windows-10-64-bit)

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\Downloads")
install.packages('ROracle_1.3-1.zip', repos = NULL)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
   package ‘ROracle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

library(ROracle)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ROracle’:
package ‘ROracle’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it 
needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
```

I have mysql and sqldeveloper on my machine.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at this [thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4151875)?Your second attempt worked for me with R 3.3.0. In fact R 3.3.0 is the latest supported version by Oracle according to the compatibility matrix.

Comment: I just downloaded R 3.3.0, and am having the same problem.  install.packages('ROracle_1.3-1.zip', repos = NULL)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
package ‘ROracle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> library(ROracle)
Loading required package: DBI
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/ROracle/libs/x64/ROracle.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Comment: I solved it by uninstalling and reinstalling Oracle Instant Client.  The most advanced R that worked was 3.4.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Download compatible versions of ROracle, Instant Client & R**

LATEST version of RTools can be downloaded from link below

**Important links:**
Instant Client Version (12.2): Download the basic as well sdk version of instant client
    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/

**R for Windows (Look for previous releases of R for Windows)**
    https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/base/old/
    https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/base/old/3.6.1/R-3.6.1-win.exe

**RTools** (RTools35)
    https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

**ROracle** (ROracle-1.3.2 is compatible with R3.6.0 version and above)
    https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/roracle-downloads.html
     Very important link for Troubleshooting ROracle: https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL

**RStudio**

Set the below environment variables in control Panel > System & Security > System> Advanced System Settings> In System properties, click on "Environment Variables"> In system variables SET BELOW:

```
ORACLE_HOME = 'C:/oreclient_install_dir/instantclient_12_2'
OCI_INC     = 'C:/oreclient_install_dir/instantclient_12_2/sdk/include'
OCI_LIB64   = 'C:/oreclient_install_dir/instantclient_12_2'
TNS_ADMIN   = 'C:/oreclient_install_dir/instantclient_12_2'
```

Please see I have installed 64-bit version of R and hence setting environment variables  for the same. If you are using 32-bit version, please set OCI_LIB32 with appropriate path. Also, place the TNS file at the appropriate location.

Also, set path to include:

```
C:\oreclient_install_dir\instantclient_12_2 <br/>
C:\app\client\pc_username\product\12.2.0\client_1  
C:\app\client\pc_username\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin  
C:\app\client\pc_username\product\12.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin  
%PATH%
C:\R\R-3.6.0\bin  
C:\R\Rtools\bin  
C:\R\Rtools\mingw_64\bin
```

## Few important R commands to check the variables set:

```r
R.home(component = "home")
Sys.getenv("PATH")
Sys.getenv("OCI_INC")
Sys.getenv("OCI_LIB64")
Sys.getenv("ORACLE_HOME")
Sys.getenv("TNS_ADMIN")
```

Please re-start R when the env variables are set and it is recommended to run R as administrator when running ROracle commands.

**install.packages("C:/ROracle/ROracle_1.3-2.tar.gz", repos = NULL)**

you may need to install DBI package as well

```
install.packages("DBI")
library("DBI")
library("ROracle")
```