# ROracle on R Version 4.0.0

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

When trying to use ROracle I get the following error message

```
>   library("ROracle")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ROracle’:
package ‘ROracle’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
```

I've installed/downloaded DBI, RTools, oracle isntant client (basic + sdk) and tried following these instructions but it did not work: [ROracle install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066911/roracle-install)

I'm able to download ROracle just fine (see below) so I'm stumped on what is missing. Do I need to downgrade a version?

```
>   Roracle_path <- "filepath.../ROracle_1.3-2.zip"
>   install.packages(Roracle_path, repos = NULL)

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/<my username>/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
package ‘ROracle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

Comment: I might be doing something wrong too, but I haven't been able to get ROracle to work on R4.0+. I have just used R 3.6 for the moment if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

ROracle_1.3-2.tar.gz which is built for R 3.6.x works also with R 4.x if you install the package from **SOURCES**.

On Linux systems at first you have to install the Oracle Instant Client basic and SDK:

```
/home/jovyan/R
unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /opt/oracle/

unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /opt/oracle
```

The linux package libaio1 have to be installed on the system:

```
apt install -y libaio1
```

Next, the environment variables must be set:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4"
```

Finally the package can be installed from Sources (use ROracle_1.3-2.tar.gz (sources) but not ROracle_1.3-2_R_x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz (binary) ):

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-oci-lib=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4/ --with-oci-inc=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4/sdk/include' ROracle_1.3-2.tar.gz
```

During the installation process you will see that the package will be installed from SOURCES:

```
 * installing to library ‘/opt/conda/lib/R/library’
 * installing *source* package ‘ROracle’ ...
 ** using staged installation
 configure: creating ./config.status
 config.status: creating src/Makevars
 ** libs
 x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -I"/opt/conda/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4/sdk/include  -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /opt/conda/include -I/opt/conda/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/conda/lib   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /opt/conda/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base-split_1639563404388/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.1.2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/conda=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c rodbi.c -o rodbi.o
 x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -I"/opt/conda/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4/sdk/include  -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /opt/conda/include -I/opt/conda/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/conda/lib   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /opt/conda/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base-split_1639563404388/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.1.2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/conda=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c rooci.c -o rooci.o
 x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -shared -L/opt/conda/lib/R/lib -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-rpath,/opt/conda/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/conda/lib -L/opt/conda/lib -o ROracle.so rodbi.o rooci.o -L/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4/ -lclntsh -Wl,-rpath,/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4/ -L/opt/conda/lib/R/lib -lR
 installing to /opt/conda/lib/R/library/00LOCK-ROracle/00new/ROracle/libs
 ** R
 ** inst
 ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
 ** help
 *** installing help indices
 ** building package indices
 ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
 ** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
 ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
 ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation     path
 * DONE (ROracle)
 #
```

Check the line in the output to see it will be installed from Sources:

```
     * installing *source* package ‘ROracle’ ...
```

Comment: For ease of finding it, ROracle is available from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/roracle-downloads.html

Comment: Could you tell please how to install ROracle on Windows?

Comment: @ChristopherJones  Do you have further information, why the binary package ROracle is not available for R 4.x?

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded to R 3.6.3 and used RTools 35 and now it works.